# PHP and Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: php, wcf, windows-authentication

In C#, it's kind of easy to use windows credentials for making another web request from a web request (using webclient) :
[WCF impersonation/ Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619227/wcf-impersonation-authentication)

Is it possible to make the same with PHP ?
I have a WCF web service that I would call from a PHP script who is on another server that the one where the PHP script is hosted.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: You could probably do some kind of LDAP query against Active Directory to authenticate a user. There's probably a library out there for that purpose.

Comment: Found it right here on Stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171519/authenticating-in-php-using-ldap-through-active-directory

Comment: Thanks Doug. However, is it possible to use the integrated windows authentication to login ?

Comment: If the PHP script was executed by IIS, IIS can use Windows authentication to allow Windows users to execute the script, but I don't know of a way to pass the authentication token from PHP to WCF.